# Backspace can't be detected in linux terminal , K&R 1.10 exercize

Tags: c, linux, konsole

i was trying to do the execize 1.10 of k&r so this is :

```
/* 
 * Exercise 1.10
 *
 * Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab 
 * by \t, each backspace by \b, and each backslash by \\. This makes tab 
 * and backspaces visible in an unambiguous way.
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t')
            printf("\\t");
        else if (c == '\b')
            printf("\\b");
        else if (c == '\\')
            printf("\\\\");
        else
            printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

If i compile this code with `gcc -std=c99 1.10.c -o test`
it doesn't print `\b` if i use <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Why? And how I could try to get `\b` pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Linux ?

A guy has said me:

> Your program probably doesn't see that backspace. Terminals buffer by line, by default. So does stdin. Well, stdin's buffering is IDB.

Comment: That exercise is intended to work on very old UNIX machines. I think that the way terminals work has changed since that time.

Comment: You might need to execute your code on an `ansi` or `vt100` terminal emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the console interprets special characters, like <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>. You can instruct the console to not do this with [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty).

Before you run the program, you can set the tty to ignore backspace mode with

```
stty erase ''
```

and restore the console afterwards with

```
stty sane
```

This passes the backspace characters <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> unchanged to the program you're running.

---

If this doesn't show any difference, then the backspace key may be mapped to <kbd>DEL</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>.

In this case you can just start your program and type <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> everywhere you would have used the backspace key. If you want to catch the backspace key nevertheless, you must also  check for `DEL`, which is [ASCII `127`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart)

```
/* ... */
else if (c == '\b' || c == 127)
    printf("\\b");
```

Comment: well even typing your code before i run my program ,  \b is not printed .

Comment: Then your backspace key isn't `Ctrl-h`, but `DEL`. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int mygetch(void)
{


 struct termios oldt,
    newt;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
    return ch;
}
```

use getch then get the ASCII for backsapce using it, no need for enter or to clean input buffer and it returns an int.
Enjoy

Comment: mm to much complicated for one that is at page 16 of K&R ?? anyway thank you , maybe i will understastand your code after a while :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because it's intended to run on very old UNIX machines. On modern terminals, the backspace character won't be considered.